# WinAPI's MessageBox in Java

Tags: java, winapi

I'm looking for a quick and dirty way in Java to flash up a message box to the user, to return when they click OK. It's for an application termination condition, so I'm really not interested in oh here's mah JFrame and all the rest of it. The MessageBox function in the Windows API is exactly what I want, except I'm stuck in Javaland. Any recommendations for similar functions?

Edit: Now that I come to think of it, how the hell do you exit a Java app? The only way I've ever managed to close mine is by making a JFrame and having EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

Edit: Got it.

Comment: You can call System.exit(n) to exit an application, where n is generally 0 for normal exit, and any other int value to indicate an error.

Comment: @Rulmeq: Thanks, but I found it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "blah blah blah");
```

it shows a message box centered relative to the screen, with an 'ok' button

Answer (score 3):

[Dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score -2):

Security issues makes your own dialog (not the system one) the best solution.

// edit
"own dialog" - I meant a dialog that runs in virtual machine

Comment: I downvoted because there are absolutely no security issues whatsoever with the system MessageBox.